# Origine de l'expression "tout un chacun"

Tags: expressions, étymologie

*Tout un chacun* signifie *tout le monde*, ou encore *n'importe qui*, en fonction du contexte.

> Tout un chacun peut entrer, c'est un lieu public.

Quelle est l'origine de cette expression, et pourquoi cette construction assez étrange ?

Answer (score 3):

Il s'agit probablement d'une collision entre les expressions :

- *un chacun* (déjà lourde, car chacun = chaque un), qui a un sens distributif ;

et de :

- *tout chacun*, qui est exhaustif.

Les deux expressions étaient déjà condamnées dans le dictionnaire de Furetière, mais leur fusion s'est imposée, sans doute car l'expression est très commode.

On peut voir une autre collision dans le regrettable mais inévitable "aujourd'hui", littéralement "au jour de ce jour" (et certains en ajoutent, en disant l'affreux "au jour d'aujourd'hui".

Answer (score 2):

Il semble que le nœud de cette formule soit l'expression *un chacun*, avec un sens proche de ce que l'on comprend aujourd'hui : *Ils ont reçu des bonbons, un chacun* : chaque personne a un bonbon.

L'expression **un chacun** a [une étymologie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/chacun) : elle apparaît au XII<sup>e</sup> siècle dans un sermon, pour exprimer une distribution étalée dans le temps.

Mais… je n'ai pas retrouvé d'étymologie pour *tout un chacun*.

Le TLF donne sur [le mot chacun](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chacun) de nombreux exemples des expressions *un chacun* et *tout un chacun*, mais malheureusement sans en donner ni la définition ni l'étymologie.